# Dolphin does not show thumbnails

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, dolphin, thumbnails

I have changed my Unity default file manager to [Dolphin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/dolphin/).

Problem: video thumbnails don't show up anymore.
In Nautilus the thumbnails are shown correctly.

How to make Dolphin show thumbnails?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Thumbnailer**

To show thumbnails the Dolphin will need the thumbnail plug in.

[image]

Video thumbnailers for the Dolphin:

```
:~$ apt-cache show ffmpegthumbs
Package: ffmpegthumbs
Priority: optional
Section: universe/kde
...
Description: video thumbnail generator using ffmpeg
 FFMpegThumbs is a video thumbnail generator for KDE file managers
 like Dolphin and Konqueror.  It enables them to show preview images
 of video files using FFMpeg.
 .
 This package is part of the KDE multimedia module.

Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
```

.

```
:~$ apt-cache show mplayerthumbs
Package: mplayerthumbs
Priority: optional
Section: universe/kde
...
Description: video thumbnail generator using mplayer
 MPlayerThumbs is a video thumbnail generator for KDE file managers
 like Dolphin and Konqueror.  It enables them to show preview images
 of video files using MPlayer.
 .
 This package is part of the KDE multimedia module.

Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
```

.

```
:~$ apt-cache show kffmpegthumbnailer
Package: kffmpegthumbnailer
Priority: extra
Section: universe/kde
...
Description: video thumbnailer for KDE
 kffmpegthumbnailer is a video thumbnailer based on ffmpegthumbnailer.
 The thumbnailer uses ffmpeg to decode frames from the video files.

Homepage: http://www.kde-apps.org/content/show.php/kffmpegthumbnailer?content=117562
```

**Settings**

To use the thumbnail you need to enable the thumbnailer from the Dolphin settings.

[image]

Comment: @rofiquzzaki If this question helped you, please make it as the correct answer by clicking the icon under the ^ 0 v in this question.

Comment: @user26687 even with all that dolphin 15.12.3 on ubuntu 16.04 lts doesn't show thumbnails for files with spaces in their adddress.

Answer (score 6):

In a terminal run

```
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbs mplayerthumbs kffmpegthumbnailer
```

then... change in dolphin settings as says in user26687's answer... works for me kubuntu 14.04lts in laptop n4010 dell

Comment: Installed as suggested. A new menu item in dolphin appeared (Video Files (ffmpegthumbs)). However, thumbnails are still not generated :(

Comment: `ffmpegthumbs` did it for me

Answer (score 5):

1. Install the following packages: `ffmpegthumbs mplayerthumbs kffmpegthumbnailer kio-extras`
2. Restart Dolphin
3. Settings > Configure Dolphin > General > Behavior > View > Use common properties for all folders, OK
4. Press the "Preview" button

Comment: kio-extras did the trick for me, otherwise I couldn't see anything under General > Previews

Answer (score 4):

Now in Ubuntu 15.10 I needed another package for thumbnails to show:

> sudo apt-get install kio-extras