# Dolphin's "Show previews for" blank

Tags: dolphin, thumbnails

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and installed dolphin (15.12.3) + FFMpegThumbs so that I can see thumbnails of videos but when I went to the previews the box was just blank.

Comment: In the Dolphin preferences under General -> Previews the option FFMpegThumbs must be ticked. Did you check that?

Comment: I found the answer on  http://askubuntu.com/questions/411891/dolphin-thumbnail-didnt-show?rq=1 you have to install kio-extras thanks for answering step

Comment: I have `ffmpegthumbs` and `kio-extras` installed on my system and it still doesn't work. FFMpegThumbs is enabled in the Dolphin options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ffmpegthumbs 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1` [is buggy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpegthumbs/+bug/1574037) and unpacks `ffmpegthumbs.so` to the wrong location. Until the package is fixed a workaround is to link the files to the correct location:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plugins/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/`

This works on my installation of Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. By the way `ffmpegthumbs` needs `kio-extras` to work (should be installed on Kubuntu by default as a dependency of `kubuntu-desktop`).

Comment: Thanks a  ton. Was searching for a solution for hours. linking works on 16.04LTS for me.

Comment: `suo apt install kio-extras` solved the problem for me on 17.10.1

Comment: @JulianLai: The location specified by `ffmpegthumbs` used to be correct until a new location was introduced by QT5 and used by the new version of Dolphin based on QT5.

Comment: @jrouquie: `kio-extras` is always needed for Dolphin previews, this is mentioned in my answer. What really happened is that [the bug in ffmpegthumbs was fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpegthumbs/+bug/1574037). The workaround described in my answer is not necessary anymore with newer versions of Kubuntu.

Comment: `sudo apt install kio-extras` was still needed to solve the problem on Ubuntu 18.04 (not Kubuntu, where I'm glad to learn it's installed by default).