# There is no video thumbnail for Dolphin file manager on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ffmpeg, dolphin, thumbnails

I have installed "ffmpegthumbs", "mplayerthumbs", "kffmpegthumbnailer", "kio-extras", and set up everything for Dolphin which used to work on OpenSUSE 42.1, but there is still no thumbnail for videos, how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I have found that answer few minutes ago, still thanks.

Comment: No problem. Seems like an upstream bug that I suggest you tell the devs about.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, [Dolphin's "Show previews for" blank](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761005/dolphine-show-previews-for-blank)

Making sure that you have installed "kio-extras" and "ffmpegthumbs", then "sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plugins/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/"

I can't believe that they put these files in the wrong path.