# Ubuntu 18.04 File Explorer with Preview window like MS Windows File Explorer

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, lts, filemanager, previews

Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome 3.28.2 - I have a ton of documents and images that I need to go through efficiently without having to open them or hit the spacebar. I just want to select them in file explorer and have a preview similar to what Windows File Explorer generates on the side. I am using Nautilus. I do have Dolphin but have other issues there like not seeing symbolic links and no previews there either. I don't know how to obtain what I want.

Comment: Re. dolphin, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170475/dolphin-under-gnome-doesnt-display-any-thumbnail-how-to-fix/

Comment: Valid use case if you ask me, but I do not know any GTK file manager capable of directly previewing a file as you select it. For images, though, you can zoom in the thumbnails to an extent that you quite effectively can preview the image. You can enlarge thubmnails beyond the default size (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097934/nautilus-show-images-with-more-than-200-size) but it is not very pretty.

Comment: Actually, someone asked exactly the same question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69469/linux-file-manager-with-side-by-side-preview-not-thumbnails, so watch that site too.